# What is the best way to unlink hard-linked files?

Tags: shell, hard-link

Using `rdfind` I found a lot of hard-linked files (~60-90) and I want to unlink all of them. One possible solution is to just find all files `-link +1`  and just copy them, delete them and move it back to link name.

Is there a better solution? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How big is the linked file?

Comment: All of those filesizes vary from a few byte to 6GB, but all of them together arround 400GB  (thats what im guessing, just before i used rdfind) now i think its arround 200GB

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
find . -type f -links +1 -exec sh -c '
  { rm -f "$1" && cat > "$1"; } < "$1"' sh {} \;
```

but that won't preserve file metadata. On Linux, you can do instead:

```
find . -type f -links +1 -exec sh -c '
  { rm -f "$1" && cp -p /proc/self/fd/0 "$1"; } < "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Note that if `cat` or `cp` fails (like on disk full), you'll lose the file's content that `cat`/`cp` didn't manage to copy.

We use `-exec {} \;` instead of `-exec {} +` so that the link count of the file is updated after the file has been found so that `find` will not *find* the last link if the link count has dropped to 1 (which means for a file with initial link count of 4, only 3 instances will be overwritten).

With GNU `tar`, you can also do:

```
find . -type f -links +1 -print0 |
  tar --hard-dereference --null -T - -cf - | tar xpf -
```

That will run fewer commands but overwrite more files.

You may see some:

```
tar: ./file: file changed as we read it
```

for large files, but that's OK as the second `tar` will unlink the file before overwriting it so in effect, that will be very similar to the first approach. It's just the first `tar` noticing the link count decreasing (and ctime changing as a result) when the second tar unlinks the file.